# Deeplink ios after deploying the website doesn't work

Tags: ios, json, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-hosting

I hosted the website in the default domain
then I created another domain
I use the other domain to handle my deep link which works fine on Android but ios, not
ios open the preview screen then redirect to the hosted website (default domain) expected to open ios app like android
firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

need to redirect to ios app